# Why is the space of 2D lattices topologically 4D, if Gram matrices are 3D?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, quotient-spaces, modular-forms, integer-lattices

There are several good articles on the space of 2D lattices, usually represented using Eisenstein series and the invariants $G_4$ and $G_6$.

Here are some:

- http://www.stevejtrettel.com/the-space-of-lattices.html
- http://www.josleys.com/articles/ams_article/Lorenz3.htm
- https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/04/the_modular_flow_on_the_space.html

All these pages show that the space of lattices is 4-dimensional, and if degenerate lattices are included, it is isomorphic to $\Bbb C^2$, with the degenerate lattices being a trefoil knot. This seems very well known and a basic part of the theory of modular forms.

The reasoning in the first article is that the space of lattices is isomorphic to $GL(2,\Bbb R)/GL(2,\Bbb Z)$. Since $GL(2,\Bbb R)$ is a 4D manifold and $GL(2,\Bbb Z)$ is a discrete subgroup, the quotient is also 4D.

**My question:** Lattices can also be represented with positive-definite Gram matrices. These are $2 \times 2$ symmetric matrices, and hence are only 3D. For any such matrix $G$, if $M$ is a unimodular matrix, the matrix $M' G M$ represents the same lattice, so we can take the quotient and equate all such matrices. Wouldn't we then have a 3D space? Is it somehow isomorphic to the 4D one?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question precisely the way you intended. My first thought  is that if you rotate the lattice (i.e. multiply it by a complex number from the unit circle), you won't change its Gram matrix at all. Effectively we then have $SO(2,\Bbb{R})\backslash GL(2,\Bbb{R})/GL(2,\Bbb{Z})$, and that is surely 3D.

Comment: Ah, yes, ok, that makes sense. So Gram matrices represent lattices only up to rotation. I guess this is related to the Seifert fibration on the manifold. If you want to put that as an answer I'll take it...